# How to stop any application to store text in PRIMARY buffer just because it has been selected?

Tags: x11, vim, clipboard

I'm using the [`autocutsel`](http://www.nongnu.org/autocutsel/) trick in the `.xinitrc` :

```
autocutsel -fork &
autocutsel -selection PRIMARY -fork &
```

to synchronize `PRIMARY` and `CLIPBOARD` buffers so I can yank text in vim and paste it in the browser et vice versa copy some text from the browser and paste it in vim using the `p` shortcut. Problem is that when I select text in order to overwrite it with the paste it instead overwrites the clipoard buffer because of `autocutsel` and I end up pasting the same text I wanted to replace in the first place.

How do I do to keep everything as is except for the functionality that copies selected text automatically. I still want `yank` in vim to put text in `PRIMARY` but I don't want any apps to copy text just because I selected something.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question exactly as stated here, but you may want to look into clipboard managers that allow you to juggle multiple entries in your clipboard: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/clipboard

Comment: Then don't synchronize `PRIMARY` and `CLIPBOARD`?

Comment: @SatoKatsura will I still be able to copy text with `C-v` after yanking text in vim with yy ?

Comment: You'll be able to paste text with `Ctrl-v` after yanking it with `"+yy` in Vim.  You could also set `clipboard` and `guioptions` to use the `PRIMARY` selection by default.  But you won't be able to configure the system so that `PRIMARY` and `CLIPBOARD` are synchronised for some operations and unsynchronised for others.